# How access to the admin panel nova only super admin?

Tags: php, laravel

How can I make access to the admin panel new only for users who have a super admin role?
I added to NovaServiceProvider -> gate  did not help

```
 protected function gate()
    {
        Gate::define('viewNova', function ($user) {
            /** @var \App\Models\User $user */
            return $user->hasRole('super-admin');
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use NovaServiceProvider to define your own gate:

in [/app/Providers/NovaServiceProvider.php](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/installation.html)

```
protected function gate()
    {
        Gate::define('viewNova', function ($user) {
            if( !user->hasRole('super-admin') ){ 
                abort(403);
            }
            return true;
        });
    }
```

Comment: It feels like nova is ignoring my method, no matter what condition I write

Comment: @РомаЛытарь "This gate determines who can access Nova in *non-local* environments."